# How to export the file names in a folder a excel sheet using Pandas library

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a bunch of files in a folder it contains various file types like xlsx, pdf, csv etc. what I am trying to do is export the pdf file names to an excel sheet. how can it be done using pandas please help?

i used  `for file in glob.glob("*"): print (file)`
i got the output what i want is to export the output to excel sheet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `pdfs = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.pdf')]; pd.DataFrame(pdfs).to_excel('pdf_files.xlsx')`